# iron-router: replace special characters

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

To get understandable links to share, I don't want to put only the `._id` in the url but the `.name` as well.

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('here', {
        path: 'here/:_id/:name/',
        template: 'here'
    })
})
```

The Problem is that the `.name` entry can have special characters like `/`.

```
www.example.com/here/1234/name_with special-characters like / (<-this slash) /
```

Is there a way to replace the slash (and other special characters) in iron-router?
(if there is a good way to handle this, maybe in some cases I don't even need the id anymore.)

If I want to use `<a href="{{pathFor 'showCourse'}}">` 
I can not use a wildecard`path: 'here/:_id/*`

Thanks

Comment: Why would one allow slashes in names that are used as parts of `url`? Is there some specific reason you to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not specific to Iron Router, but JavaScript's native global functions `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` exist for just this purpose:

```
encodeURIComponent("foo/bar");   // returns "foo%2Fbar"
decodeURIComponent("foo%2Fbar"); // returns "foo/bar"
```

What I do in my projects is add a field called `slug` and write a function that generates an URL-friendly slug from the document's title *and* checks the collection to make sure the slug is unique (otherwise it appends "-2" or "-3" etc. as appropriate). With a `slug` or similar field that is unique per document, you can use it as the only query parameter and forgo the `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Geoffrey Booth's answer, you can do this with a template helper.

Define a template helper to encode your `name` value (I made it global so it can be reused by all templates):

```js
Template.registerHelper('encodeName', function() {
  this.name = encodeURIComponent(this.name);
  return this;
});
```

Then, in your templates, you can pass this function to iron-router's `pathFor` helper:

```html
<a href="{{pathFor 'showCourse' encodeName}}">
```

This works for me on Meteor 1.1.0.2.